# How to format the functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to format the code properly in the javascript. Is there any website or software that can do it.

Like i have a function.

```
    function e(e) {
    for (var i, s, r = e[0], l = e[1], c = e[2], _ = 0, u = []; _ < r.length; _++)
        s = r[_],
        Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(n, s) && n[s] && u.push(n[s][0]),
        n[s] = 0;
    for (i in l)
        Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(l, i) && (t[i] = l[i]);
    d && d(e);
    while (u.length)
        u.shift()();
    return o.push.apply(o, c || []),
    a()
}
```

This function names e is used the 1000 times in a file i want to rename the function name all the places as like function getSum(getsum) {}

Comment: Search for javascript linters.  Example, https://jslint.com/

Comment: You appear to be asking two very different questions.  Can you clarify?

Comment: On the other hand, [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) is more versatile. See [_A Comparison of JavaScript Linting Tools_](https://www.sitepoint.com/comparison-javascript-linting-tools/) for more information.

Comment: So you want to replace ```e``` with ```getSum```?

Comment: jslint is not working for the large codes

Comment: I am afraid that you may need to go through the file line-by-line and replace functions/variable names. It may take time, but hopefully you need to do this once. If you are attempting to reverse-engineer code that was minified, good luck. I have done it in the past and it sucks, but it can be done. A good IDE like VSCode or IntelliJ (Ultimate edition) may help you out. Basically any IDE that offers some kind of intellisense.

Comment: @person yes everywhere definition and where it is called

Comment: Use find and replace. ```Ctrl+r``` in the find put ```function e``` and in replace put ```function getSum``` this only works for definitions though.

Comment: well, probably you can replace some patterns via your editor, like `'e(' -> 'getSum('` , `'(e)' -> '(getSum)'` , `'= e' -> '= getSum' `

Comment: @person that will not help with the usage. It is better to replace `\be\(` (word-boundary followed by 'e' and an opening-parenthesis).

Comment: Yeah I wasn't thinking about function calls

Comment: Officially: This question is asking for recommendations for tools/libraries, and is therefore off-topic, as this is mostly opinion-based. Inofficially: just use VScode, select the `e` you want to rename, and hit F2 (or right click -> rename). Unless the code is very maliciously obfuscated (which oddly enough i haven't seen any JS obfuscator do so far), this works.

Comment: what if  e is also used as variable somewhere

Comment: Javascript has lexical scoping. This means as long as all the used code is available, a javascript-parser can tell which `e` belongs to what. This is only destroyed by a handful of things in javascript, all of which are bad practice, and should not occur in code that hasn't been maliciously modified to prevent readability. In other words, a minifier should not ruin your day there. I am not saying it can't happen, but it usually doesn't.

Comment: Well, one of possible solution it's translate code to AST(https://astexplorer.net/ or https://esprima.org/), find all references to method and then replace them, but it's sound too complicated

Comment: @rostegg which is what VScode does, when you rename something, at least in javascript.

Comment: @ASDFGerte rename where? Did you mean replace?

Comment: @rostegg go to VScode, select the identifier you want to rename, hit F2 or right click -> "Rename Symbol" (as mentioned in the first comment)

Comment: @ASDFGerte wow, thx for showing a useful feature

Comment: In InelliJ, this is called "Refactor". If you tell it to rename the function, it will find all the callers and update them.

Comment: Here is a [currently unanswered question, that details a few pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61560852/breaking-lexical-scope-to-prevent-finding-all-references), when it comes to renaming. As mentioned though, i have yet to encounter an obfuscator, that uses any of these. Plus, above code doesn't look obfuscated, and e.g. minifiers have no reason to do these.